# Trace-Preserving Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Given two $n\times n$ matrices $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ such that $B>0$, and $\text{tr}(B)=1$, if $A^{\dagger}BA=B$, does this necessarily imply that $A$ is unitary? How can I prove it?

Comment: Just curious. A [very similar question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1640266/matrix-equation-implies-invertibility/1640468#1640468) appeared on this site two weeks ago. Is this a homework question or is it originated from some sort of research?

Comment: It's actually part of my research. There's a big difference between the two questions, I think. This one's part of fixed point of quantum operations.

Comment: You can always rescale a positive definite $B$ to make its trace equal to 1, and in the meantime preserving the relation $A^{\dagger}BA=B$. Since every positive definite matrix is unitarily diagonalisable, you may further assume that $B$ is a positive diagonal matrix. So, apart from the difference in ground fields, your question is actually equivalent to the linked one.

Comment: I see what you mean. So in the case of complex matrices, $A$ is not necessarily unitary then, right? Coz in the other post, it says "not necessarily orthogonal."

Comment: Yes. Basically if $B^{1/2}$ denotes the (unique) positive definite square root of $B$, then $A^{\dagger}BA=B$ if and only if $A = B^{-1/2}UB^{1/2}$ for some unitary matrix $U$. Yet such an $A$ is in general not unitary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Let

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac 12&-\sqrt{\frac 38}\\
\sqrt{\frac 32}&\frac 12\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

and

$$B=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac 23&0\\
0&\frac 13\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
Then $B>0$, $\mathrm{tr}(B)=1$, and $A^\dagger BA=B$ but

$$A^\dagger A=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac 74&\sqrt{\frac 3{32}}\\
\sqrt{\frac 3{32}}&\frac 58\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how I can characterize all the matrices with this property? Any suggested textbooks/articles I can read?

Comment: Like user1551 said above, $A^\dagger BA=B$ iff $B^{-\frac 12}AB^{\frac 12}$ is unitary.